# How to mention passwords in LaTeX documents with special caracters?

Tags: symbols, characters

right now I am writing a technical report for my collegue. Therefore it is nessecary to mention a password in the document.
I did a simple

```
\documentclass[11pt,parskip=full,a4paper]{scrartcl}
...
\begin(document)
...
\begin{tabular}{ll}
adress &\url{hello@world} \\
password & 0}*YNwZ={4q9e2P \\
\end{tabular}
...
\end(document)
```

Of course this is an fictional generated password ;)

How can I implement it into my document without display problems?
Right now there are no brackets displayed after generating the pdf document.
So the collegue cant see these and gets a wrong password of course.

Do anybody know a way to fix that problem?

Best Regards.

Comment: Try with `\verb|0}*YNwZ={4q9e2P|` (replace `|` with something which does not occur in your real password)

Comment: In the future please post compilable minimal reproducible example and not just code fragments. If you test them before posting, you should be able to catch obvious errors like `\begin(document)`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz many thanks! Your first comment saved my day. Problem is declared as solved right now.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Oh, yep! Had never the situation before to use that type of text and was confronted with that type of problem for the first time. So didn't know that possibility. This article you metioned there helped me to understand the backround even a bit more. Many thanks to you!

Comment: @ terminalmoraine You're welcome!